# How to add events in iPhone using Event Kit framework

Tags: iphone, eventkit

I am making a Restaurant application in which i need to add events in calendar, events information are coming from server, if client add any event it should show in calendar for that specified date, i have used event kit frame work and successfully added one event into the calendar, however how to add multiple events in calendar using event kit.

Comment: see this [Demo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of All, Add EventKit Framework and import it in .h file. Like below.

```
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>
```

See Below Function and Modify it as per your need.

```
-(IBAction)AddEvent:(id)sender{
EKEventStore *eventSotre = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventSotre];

if([txtTitle.text isEqualToString:@""] || txtTitle.text == NULL)
    txtTitle.text=@"Event Title";

event.title= txtTitle.text; 

NSDate *duedate = pkrDate.date;
event.startDate =duedate;
event.endDate= [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:duedate];

if(switchAlarm.on==TRUE){
    NSArray *arrAlarm = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:duedate]];
    event.alarms= arrAlarm;
}

[event setCalendar:[eventSotre defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
BOOL isSuceess=[eventSotre saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

if(isSuceess){
    UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event" message:@"Event added in calendar" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertview show];
    [alertview release];
}
else{
    UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event" message:[err description] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertview show];
    [alertview release];
}
[eventSotre release];
}
```

Please modify it as per your need. I just paste it from my one of app code.

Comment: For Multiple Event You need to loop it as per your need.