# What DB do I use to update events in app?

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite

I have been running around the web trying to figure out a way I can send out updates with a new event to the iPhone app I am building.  I am pretty sure I can do it with SQLite but I have not found any tutorial that can help.  If anyone can give me a clue it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not entirely sure what your looking for here Andrew... can you give more details? Are you trying to send your app "updates"? Messages? I dont see how SQLite has anything to do with that?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to create an app for a flash mob company where we can send out new events to the app and link it with the iphone calendar

Comment: You mean 'push notifications'? Or is it a webservice that your app queries?

Comment: I think a 'push notification' will work, I was looking more along the lines to display information in the app, but that will work as well.  Thank you, and sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now here's a snippet of code

`// Create URL and gather parameter's to send to the server's php file`

`NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.yoursite.com/checkForUpdates.php?lastUpdated=%@", lastUpdated];`

`// Send data to php file`

`NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: strURL]];`

`// Store the data returned from the php file`

`NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

After you get your server up in running this is literally all the code you'll need to get started with receiving updates from your server. One way to go about it is to create a database that holds all your update data and the date and time it was added. Create a php file on your server that receives that data(containing the last Update) that we just sent. The php file looks something like this:

```
<?php
   // Database Data
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'userName';
$db_pwd = 'password';

// Updates database
$database = 'updates_Database';

// check connection to database
if(!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd)) 
    die("Cant connect to database");

// check selection of database
if(!mysql_select_db($database))
die("Can't select database");

// Get values from the URL's(Just requested by app) 
$lastUpdated = $_GET['lastUpdated'];

// Query database for updates made after the user's last update
$sql_Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Updates
WHERE dateAdded > '$lastUpdated'");
?>
```

This will log you into your database,  take the data(lastUpdated) you just sent from the app and compare it to the updates in your database. You can then get the data from the query using `mysql_fetch_array($sql_Query)`

and finally when your all done with your data you can simply go: `echo($myData);` to send your data back to your app as an `NSString` As I stated before some devs really like using JSON to accomplish that part because it's very simple and very scaleable, I however don't really need it at the moment. I hope this helps you out man! Let me know if you need some clarification.

Comment: Awesome thank you for all of your help.  And just to clarify the PHP file would be separate from all of the other code?

Comment: Anytime man and yes you can actually just save that code as anytime you want, let's just call it checkUpdates.php and store it on your web server. After that anytime your app request the URL `www.yourwebsite.com/checkUpdates.php` they'll be directed to the checkUpdates.php on your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, you want to be able to check your database for any new updates upon launching, if so, show the user the event in a new view and allow them to add calendar events?

Comment: So that wold be using the Events framework if I am not mistaken correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct, but I feel that would be the easier part of the problem you're trying to solve as there are plenty of devs that have implemented EventKit, here's a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530687/how-to-add-events-in-iphone-using-event-kit-framework, the harder part of your equation would be communicating with your database, I can show you how I do it if you haven't done it yet. Just let me know if you need a little extra clarification.

Comment: That would be great if you could give me some guidance, I have only built one simple app so far.  Thank you for your help and support

Comment: Sure man anytime. Okay now to preface this entire thing, I need to know how proficient you are with the technologies used(they're aren't as difficult as you may think). A great way to accomplish something like that is: App launches, your app sends a command to a PHP file on your web server that checks for any updates, if so, the php file returns the data, if data returned, then show user the custom event view(which would contain the code from that other question I showed you), that really should be it.(Cont'd in next comment)

Comment: (Continued)Believe it or not you can actually communicate with a regular SQL database on a web server with just one or two lines of code. Before I show you the code, how's your PHP? And do you already have a web server?

Comment: I do not have a server, though I was just looking into the Amazon Web Server service, and my PHP needs some work.

Comment: Luckily you really don't need much PHP knowledge(I didn't have any initially). I use [Host Gator](http://www.hostgator.com) for my web hosting, they allow you to have an unlimited amount of databases and they support PHP. But it seems like the only thing your PHP file has to do is receive the last time the user has requested updates(So you won't send them something they already have, (another way to do this is just assign each user a uID)), after you know which updates to send, send them to the user. Many people use JSON for large amounts of data but I just receive that data as a `NSString`

Comment: Let me know if you have any other questions or you want to go a little further.

Comment: So to clarify just a PHP as a POST method in the app from the SQL server?

Comment: I think you got the basic idea. I'll add me reply as a separate answer to show you the code.