# How can I recreate or inherit from this viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This is shown when you try to create an event on iphone: 
http://postimage.org/image/mlx00ycwr/

I want the exact same features like seen on the picture above to be used for something else.

Can I for example inherit this viewcontroller or something to that affect?, so that I don't have to recreate it all I mean.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say that (in general) if you want to duplicate another app's functionality in your own app, you're going to have to either create it yourself ***or*** find some library or open source framework that does it for you.

That said, this appears to be an event you're trying to add.  I think you might be able to pick up some of this functionality in EventKit. There are other questions ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530687/how-to-add-events-in-iphone-using-event-kit-framework)) here on StackOverflow that you can look up that should be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your link, but you both misunderstood my question. I just want to duplicate the gui, not the adding event functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You have to recreate the whole UI and use the `EventKit` framework to manipulate the User's Calendar database.