# Adding particular date in default calender as an event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new in iPhone development.
There is a requirement in my application in which, there is a web service link which is below:

http://01s.in/webservices/sikhcalendar/getData.php?db_table=cal

so i want that the particular date which are shown in link, that date should be added in iCal which are add in my end in app. and it should generate an alert view on that particular day.

So, I am not getting how to add an event in iCal. Please give me some answer for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add events in iPhone using Event Kit framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530687/how-to-add-events-in-iphone-using-event-kit-framework)

Answer (score 0):

adding a date in ical first you have to add the two framework in your code i.e.`EventKit/EventKit.h`, `EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h` and conforms the class to `EKEventEditViewDelegate` delegate  and use the below method to add date in iCal

```
- (void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action
```

and i recommend you to go through [this url](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EventKitUIFrameworkRef/_index.html) and learn about these framework

Answer (score 0):

Adding Event on the default calendar can be done using the following function

---

```
-(void)createEvent :(NSString *)eventTitle: (NSURL *)eventURL: (NSString *)eventNotes: (NSDate *)eventStartDate: (NSDate *)eventEndDate{
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title = eventTitle;
event.URL = eventURL;
event.notes = eventNotes;
event.startDate = eventStartDate;
event.endDate   = eventEndDate;
[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
EKAlarm *myAlarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:0];
[event addAlarm:myAlarm];
NSError *err;
BOOL success = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
NSLog(@"event created success if value = 1 : %d", success);}
```

---

Here eventStartDate would be the time when the alarm which you set gets executed, and you get a notification

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look into the EventKit framwork and the Apple Documentation.

Everything is there :)

[Apple Documentation Calendar/Reminder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765)