# How i can access Calendar Event and Schedular Event in our app?

Tags: iphone, ios, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add events in iPhone using Event Kit framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530687/how-to-add-events-in-iphone-using-event-kit-framework)
>   [Adding particular date in default calender as an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072017/adding-particular-date-in-default-calender-as-an-event)

I am making an application in which i wanna use existing calendar events and schedular event in my app in iPhone. 
and i also want to edit events through my app..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Import **EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h, EventKit/EventKit.h** frameworks in your header file. This is the code to add an event to Default iPhone calendar

```
-(IBAction) addEvent:(id)sender 
  { 
       EKEventStore *eventStore = [[[EKEventStore alloc] init] autorelease]; 
       EKEvent *events = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
       events.title = @"Title";
       events.notes = @"Description";
       events.location = @"Location";
       events.startDate = [NSDate date];
       events.endDate = [NSDate date];
       events.availability = EKEventAvailabilityFree;          
       [events setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
       NSError *err;
       [eventStore saveEvent:events span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
       NSLog(@"Error From iCal : %@", [err description]);
    }
```

Then to view the Events you can use `EKEventEditViewController`

```
EKEventEditViewController *editViewController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
editViewController.editViewDelegate = self;
editViewController.event = event3;
editViewController.eventStore = eventStore1;
[self presentModalViewController:editViewController animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Refer EventKit framework to accomplish these.
The apple documentation is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).