# Sync iPhone Calendar with your application

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, synchronization

Is it possible to sync iPhone Calendar with a iphone app developed using Xcode.

Please tell me some good tutorials from where i can go through and learn it

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Link :- https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

Check Link :- https://github.com/kovpas/PMCalendar

And Add Event in your native calender [Check Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530687/how-to-add-events-in-iphone-using-event-kit-framework)

Hope it help to You

Comment: I want to add event to my native or local iphone calendar .

Comment: @zeeshnshaikh check my update ans.

Comment: check this tutorial  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-google-calendars--mobile-19155